# 504 Gateway Time-out Winginx

Tags: nginx, winginx

Сначала установил Winginx в системную папку на компьютере, очень зря.. Что я понял уже довольно поздно. Все работало до тех пор пока мне не пришлось орудовать файлами на сервере и пришлось переместить сервер в другое место. Удалил всю папку WinGinx, включил установщик, поставил заново в "C:\Winginx".

Проверил localhost, все работает, добавил новый проект, кинул туда файлы с прежнего сервера, получаю "504 Gateway Time-out". Долго мучался с таймаутами, поставил `fastcgi_connect_timeout 10;`, но это были 10 секунд бесполезного ожидания, а ведь раньше я ничего даже не надстраивал что бы сайт работал.

localhost/phpinfo.php работает нормально, но другие проекты не запускают php файлы почему-то. На localhost по умолчанию нет своих конфигов, я ничего и не ставил. Любой проект грузят все файлы кроме .php.

В логах при подключении получаю такую ошибку:

> [notice] signal process started
>
> [error] 16060#7760: *17 upstream timed
>   out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: мой домен, request:
>   "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "мой
>   домен"

Что это такое? В прошлый раз все ведь отлично работало! Тем более что говорит что проблемы с таймаутами, этого быть не может. Сайт ничем не нагруженный, да и в прошлый раз таймауты я не менял. Плюс я ставил таймауты до 60с, что просто затянуло время ожидания до ошибки 504.

Я порылся в сети на эту тему, нашел информацию про php-fpm, но так и не понял что это и зачем, хотя многие запрашивали конфиги этого, а у меня их нет нигде, я проверил все.

В конфигах nginx есть строчка:

```
fastcgi_pass localhost:9071;
```

В конфигах сайта есть похожая строка:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Когда я посмотрел какие порты чем заняты, я заметил что порт 9000 отсутствует вовсе, а порт 9071 занят процессом php-cgi.exe. (хотя по умолчанию должен быть порт 9000, а я ничего не менял).

Использую Winginx, Windows 10, nginx version 1.12.0, PHP Version 7.1.5. Если нужна какая-либо дополнительная информация - спрашивайте, я не уверен что еще стоит предоставить для решения вопроса.

Благодарю за внимание!

---

Конфиги сайта выглядят так, я их даже не менял:

```html
server {
 listen 127.0.0.1:80;
 server_name music-portfolio.com www.music-portfolio.com;

 root home/music-portfolio.com/public_html/;

 index index.php index.html;

 log_not_found off;
 access_log logs/music-portfolio.com-access.log;

 charset utf-8;

 location ~ /\. { deny all; }
 location = /favicon.ico { }
 location = /robots.txt { }

 location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
 }
 


}
```

nginx.conf:

```html
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        temp/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    client_max_body_size 55m;

    #gzip  on;

 scgi_temp_path  temp/uwsgi_temp 1 2;
 uwsgi_temp_path  temp/uwsgi_temp 1 2;

 fastcgi_connect_timeout 1;


 server {
  listen   127.0.0.1:80;

  root home/localhost/public_html;
  index index.php index.html;

  log_not_found off;
        charset utf-8;

  access_log  logs/access.log  main;

  location ~ /\. {deny all;}

  location / {

   if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
    root home/$2/public_html;
    access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
   }

  }

        location ~ \.php$ {

   if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
    root home/$2/public_html;
    access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
   }

   if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
   fastcgi_pass localhost:9071;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

   include fastcgi_params;

        }
 }

 server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:443;
  include ssl.conf;

  root home/localhost/public_html;
  index index.php index.html;

  log_not_found off;
        charset utf-8;

  access_log  logs/access.log  main;

  location ~ /\. {deny all;}

  location / {

   if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
    root home/$2/public_html;
    access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
   }

  }

        location ~ \.php$ {

   if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){
    root home/$2/public_html;
    access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;
   }

   if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
   fastcgi_pass localhost:9071;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

   include fastcgi_params;

        }
 }


 include tools-*.conf;

 include vhosts/*.conf;

}
```

Comment: А что вообще живёт на порту 9000?

Comment: @Alexander T приветствую! Я с вами, похоже, говорил на англ. версии сайта. Я там обновил вопрос со всеми подробностями и тут обновлю чуть пожже. На 9000 не живет ничего, вообще пусто. Зато на 9071 стоит php-cgi.exe, который прописан в fastcgi_pass в основном конфиге Nginx.

Comment: Занятная штука. А можно показать все конфиги nginx?

Comment: @Alexander T обновил вопрос, добавил nginx.conf.

Comment: Ну я бы предложил прописать в конфигурации сайта порт 9071 и посмотреть что будет. По идее если на 9000 порту ничего не крутится, то должна быть 502 ошибка, но я могу ошибаться.

Comment: @Alexander T что происходит с этой штукой.. Только что он просто заработал без изменений, потом перестал работать, я изменил порт на 9071 и стало работать снова, после чего перестало, но на 9001 стало работать вновь, после чего я изменил еще несколько раз и вот до сих пор нормально работает на 9071. Ошибка 504, была, я ее просто скопировал оттуда, так что.. врядли я ошибался..

Comment: Я предлагаю сделать чистую установку с нуля и сразу прописать порт 9071. Ну и вообще не надо заниматься такими вещами под Windows. Можно поставить виртуалку с Linux и делать это там.

Comment: @Alexander Сразу прописать? Там установка такая простая что я вообще ничего почти не нажимаю. Почему-то программа решила что порт 9000 не подходит, наверное. На счет виртуалки я уже слышал, но это значит там будет и сервер и управлять им через консоль и писать код там же на линуксе? Или эо будет сервер к которому можно будет подключится и с Windows? Ибо честно говоря мне удобнее работать в виндоус, но проблемы с серверами это просто смешно, разделить среду для программирования и сервера я в принципе не против.

Comment: Можно разрабатывать где угодно, а потом заливать код на виртуалку любым удобным способом. Я раньше использовал WinSCP, потом перешел на Eclipse c плагином позволяющим подключаться на удалённую машину и там работать. Ну и можно делать workflow через  Git как взрослый.

Comment: @Alexander T каждый раз заливать измененные файлы на сервер? Я каждый файл редактирую по 10-20 раз перед тем как что-то начинает работать, это будет довольно долго :) Спасибо за помощь в любом случае, я подумаю в ближайшем будущем о сервере на линукс.(можете оставить то предложение как ответ. Я в любом случае подожду сутки пока может что-то вновь откажет, а потом создам ответ если его не будет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**По результату обсужения в комментариях.**

Очень странное поведение системы. Я предлагаю переставить в нуля `nginx` и прописать в конфиге `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9071` вместо `127.0.0.1:9000`, т.к. судя по всему обработчик php висит на порту 9071, а не на 9000.

Comment: Окей, еще раз спасибо. Я подожду до завтра и выберу это как ответ если все продолжит работать.

Comment: Я понимаю что это нечто не по теме, но у меня осталась еще одна проблема с NGINX. При отправке запроса из формы на страницу проверки, путь к которой переписан и выглядит как /formcheck, я получаю ответ 405 (Not Allowed). Не подскажете какой файл отвечает за запреты на методы? В nginx.conf или конфах сайта нет никаких запретов, впрочем они описаны выше, если я чего не понимаю...

Comment: @Telion, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы

Answer (score 1):

Тут внимательно нужно посмотреть порты. 9071 - это версия 7PHP, посмотрите какая версия запущена в данный момент, если 5.6 то порт будет 9056.

Ещё вариант, в C:\Winginx\php56 или php71 (в зависимости от версии) открыть блокнотом php.ini и расскоментировать extension=php_mysql.dll и
extension=php_mysqli.dll. При этом попробуйте зайти на phpmyadmin по 81 порту, если PHP будет ругаться на отсутствие libmysql.dll - то скачать и закинуть в системную папку, при этом не забудьте перезапустить всю сборку.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это такое поведение в крайней версии конфигуратора Winginx.
Если при создании доена через него, выбрать PHP по умолчанию, тогда для fastcgi прописывается порт 9000, а если выбрать php 7.1, то порт 9071
Вобще-то, достаточно остроумно и удобно, но наверное стоило-бы оповестить юзеров об этой фиче ;)

Хотя, в принципе, все это можно увидеть в настройках:
«Настройки» -> «Версии PHP» -> Listen (IP:port) = 127.0.0.1:9071

Answer (score 0):

В последней версии Winginx не устанавливается автоматически версия php.
Нужно в настройках проекта выбрать "Server Config".
В левой части перейти к разделу PHP и выбрать нужную версию.
[image: настройки]